# In Counterpart, if the crossing is only in the underground tunnel, how does Interface work?

Tags: counterpart-series

In the show Counterpart, very early on we are shown daily, secret, coded conversations between people on opposite sides of glass in private booths.  We soon learn that the main character, Howard Silk, is one of these "Interface" people, and that he really has very little idea about what his job is really *about*.

We then soon learn that there in fact is an alternate Earth, and that the "crossing" between worlds is in an underground tunnel underneath the building where Howard Silk works.  Over the course of the series we're also shown that:

- Crossing over to the other side requires a lot of security clearance, and in fact the issuance of a visa, which could be valid for as short as a few hours.  So crossing is a big deal, not necessarily part of a daily commute.
- The "Interface" workers presumably don't have the necessary clearance, since Howard spent years in his job at Interface and never knew about the existence of the other world, so clearly never crossed over.  I think it's safe to assume that the Interface workers from the other side are similarly ignorant, with insufficient clearance to cross over. (And in fact in a later episode, we see two characters in an interface booth, having watched how they both arrived there, and neither one went through the crossing.)

So if the Interface workers are not crossing over to the other side, and crossing can only be achieved through the underground tunnel... how can they sit face to face in the booths to have the coded conversations?

(If someone wants to edit this to hide spoilers, feel free, but considering this is only the third question tagged about Counterpart, I kind of felt it unnecessary...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the crossing is not just in the tunnel.  There must be an adjacent area which also lies on the plane adjoining the two worlds, and the Interface rooms were built to provide separation along that line.

The evidence for this is the "last room", where the two-world-interface nature of the room is clear.  Ian Shaw describes it in S02E09:

> Last room.  Management sets it aside for off-book activities.  Exchange of goods.

Unlike other Interface rooms, there is no permanent divider, only a massive door.

The fact that this room is divided between the worlds is emphasized in the final scene of the episode, when Mira takes one Management communication device from each world and sets them up on either side of the last room's dividing line, and uses them to communicate to both worlds simultaneously.

If we understand that the joint between the two worlds extends beyond the tunnel and includes the last Interface room, then we can assume that the other Interface rooms also lie along that joint and are permanently divided by glass where the two worlds meet.